# python tk tkinter multiple canvas can not afford in my scrollable frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, canvas, frame

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg,  NavigationToolbar2Tk) 
from matplotlib.figure import Figure 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from data import dataprocess
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1500x800')
container = tk.Frame(root)
main_canvas = tk.Canvas(container, width=1480, height=800,  bg='blue')
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=main_canvas.yview)
scrollable_frame = tk.Canvas(main_canvas, bg='black')
scrollable_frame.bind(
"<Configure>",
lambda e: main_canvas.configure(
    scrollregion=main_canvas.bbox("all")
    )
)

main_canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")

main_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

for i in range(100):
    f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
    a = f.add_subplot(111)
    a.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[5,6,1,3,8,9,3,5])
    a.set_title("fig" + str(i))
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, 
                           master = scrollable_frame)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=i, column=0)

container.grid()
main_canvas.grid()
scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nse")
container.mainloop()
```

I would like to generate lots of canvas on my scorllable frame, but it seems failed by maxiumn canvas size. Is there any method to fix it?
[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spoCL.png)

Comment: The scrollable frame needs to be a Frame, not a Canvas.

Comment: May be using multiple columns instead of single column.  Or using `main_canvas.create_window()` instead of scrollable frame.  However your approach will significantly slow down your system performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take a guess and say that what you really want is a ScrolledText widget. Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg,  NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1500x800')
scrollable_frame = ScrolledText(root)
scrollable_frame.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)

for i in range(10):
    f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
    a = f.add_subplot(111)
    a.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[5,6,1,3,8,9,3,5])
    a.set_title("fig" + str(i))
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f)
    scrollable_frame.window_create(tk.END, window=canvas.get_tk_widget())
    scrollable_frame.insert(tk.END, '\n')

root.mainloop()
```

100 graphs will be very taxing no matter what, on the computer and the human. I think it would be better to design your program differently so that the graph is updated rather than scrolling through many graphs.

Comment: The above code worked!  How can I do if I want 'grid'  instead of 'pack' method. I also want to add some widget such as buttons and Labels in ScrolledText. 
Thank for your suggestion about my designation, however, it is for specific purpose.

Comment: The widgets do not use grid or pack inside a Text or Canvas, you only use those when adding to a Frame type. To add Buttons you would add them with the `window_create` method, just like I used for the graph. You can add Labels that way too, but the Text widget supports raw text so you probably want to use `insert()` for that.

To put the Text object into the root window I used pack(), but you can just swap that for grid() if you want.

Comment: I success. Here is a new problem about I only want to change figure 1~5 without re-plot all figures. Any suggestion?

Comment: @curry just keep the reference to the plot and update it with set_data(). If you need help with that make a new post.

Comment: I might know your meaning. I still have no idea how to put reference id to each plot and update with set_data(). Can you give me some sample code or reference link. I appreciate it.